# Convert entire data set into numeric form during retrieving the file

Tags: r, shiny

i am working on Shiny app and want to convert entire data set into numeric form.I have used this code for retrieving file from local PC. what changes can be done that while retrieving i can convert entire data set into numeric form

```
datami <- reactive({
file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)})

output$table <- renderPrint({
if(is.null(datami())){return ()}
str(datami())})
```

````
tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Data",div(h5("Data",style="color:red")),verbatimTextOutput("table"))```
````

Comment: Hi you can use code to make multiple column numeric by ```data[,1:15] <- sapply(data[,1:15],as.numeric) ``` hope this will help.

Comment: some variables have characters like "A","B".while running this i got error  In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Okay ...! Then if you want that column to Character then  do ```data[,1:15] <- sapply(data[,1:15],as.character)```

Comment: i wan to convert in numeric form..but i have column which contains character A B C D i also want to convert them in 1 2 3 .,but while using  mm4 <-reactive({ lapply(mmi2(),as.integer) 
        }) the column whch are in character form shows NA instead of 1 2 3

Comment: Yes,this will do the job,make it first as.factor and then convert to numeric. example ```df <- data.frame(ID=c('A','B','C'))
                                                       df$ID <- as.numeric(df$ID)```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to deal with lower/uppercase letters (if you have them in your data) we could do one of the following:

MRE:

```
letter_variable <- c(letters, LETTERS)
```

Same numeric value for upper and lower case letters:

```
letter_variable_as_numeric1 <- as.numeric(factor(toupper(letter_variable), levels = LETTERS))

 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
[22] 22 23 24 25 26  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[43] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Different numeric value for upper and lower case letters:

```
letter_variable_as_numeric2 <- as.numeric(factor(letter_variable), levels = c(letters, LETTERS))


 [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41
[22] 43 45 47 49 51  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32
[43] 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52
```